# Почему Windows 10 1709 видит весь объем RAM, а использует только половину?

Tags: windows, администрирование

В последнее время стал глючить один комп, и я заметил вот такую вещь

[image: пример]

и это случилось после последнего обновления системы. Предыдущая версия Win10 работала с полным объемом памяти.

`msconfig` смотрел, там никаких ограничений не установлено, установить принудительно нужный объем пока не рискнул. Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Скорее всего половина памяти занята кэшем. Переключитесь на вкладку Память и посмотрите значения у "Выделено" и "Кэшировано"

Comment: @Sublihim а это где? Вкладка `Хранилище`?

Comment: @Buslon ну у вас выделено сейчас ЦП, кликните на Память. Или откройте "Монитор ресурсов" (значок внизу виден у вас на картинке) И там посмотрите на вкладке Память

Comment: @Sublihim ну, кроме всего там написано, что Зарезервировано аппаратно: 4 Гб. И что с этим делать?

Comment: msconfig -> Загрузка -> Дополнительные параметры... -> снимите флажок Максимум памяти. Перезагрузите компьютер. Или ищите в BIOS Memory Remapping (или что-то связанное с Remapping если у вас есть такой параметр) и включите его в Enable

Comment: @Sublihim там как раз флажок не стоял, а сейчас я его поставил.. и пробую перезагрузится.

Comment: @Sublihim, к сожалению, не сброс настроек BIOS, не msconfig ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До сих пор во всех случаях, когда часть памяти была помечена как "зарезервировано аппаратно" помогали лишь следующие шаги:

1. Вариант, уже описанный выше, связанный с настройками в BIOS (Memory remap,  Continuous memory map и т.п.). Помогает крайне редко, в основном, на ноутбуках, ибо причиной чаще всего является не опция в BIOS.
2. Если модулей больше, чем один, - несовместимость. Помогает замена одного из модулей, либо, если число слотов > 2, разнесение в разные пары слотов.
3. Банальный неконтакт/неполное вставление/прочая ерунда (один раз был даже кусочек фольги на контактах) - простое устранение причины.

Кстати, Windows XP, к примеру, и Windows 10 могут по-разному видеть объём установленной памяти, возможно, в Windows 10 используется более агрессивный тестер RAM.

Из примеров: когда райзены стали появляться на рынке, купили в компанию несколько комплектов мат. плата + процессор + память на тесты. Подобная проблема наблюдалась почти на всех комплектах, пока не сообразили вставлять разные модули в разные пары слотов.

2 домашних примера:

1. увеличивал объём памяти на ноутбуке путём вставления доп. планки. BIOS видит установленную память, CPUID видит эту память, Windows 10 пишет, что она зарезервирована. Путём повторного разбирания, протирки и чистки контактов проблема была устранена.
2. Сын уронил свой ноутбук, сломал сенсорный экран (теперь не работает управление пальцем) и получил ту же проблему с памятью. Путём разборки/чистки проблема была устранена.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но компьютер не подвергался никаким модернизациям, никто его не разбирал и ничего в нем не менял. Он как был собран 9 лет назад, так и эксплуатировался. Обновлялся только софт.

Comment: @Bulson Сейчас дополню ответ пояснениями и примерами

Comment: Хорошо, если есть еще какие идеи, а то я уже подумываю об апгрейде.

Comment: Попробуйте загрузиться с флешки/диска в другую ОС. если она увидит всю память, значит, с железом всё-таки ничего не произошло, просто у Win10 возросли требования к ошибкам памяти. Можно попытаться почистить контакты, увеличить тайминги памяти, слегка поднять напряжение и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.